# event.preventDefault() blocks all onclick events instead of just one

Tags: asp.net, jquery, preventdefault

I wanted to brand my ASP.NET FileUpload control, and since that can't be done OOB I chose to just copy it's functionality with javascript.

I attach the 'browse' buttons `onclick` event to my button and use `event.preventDefault()` which works as intended. But I also have 2 other buttons; Save, Delete, which are normal asp.net buttons. After I trigger the `onclick` event on my "custom" browse button, the two other buttons `onclick` events won't trigger.

[Javascript]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // The "custom" browse button.
    $('#<%=ProfilePictureBrowsePicture.ClientID%>').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#<%=ProfilePictureUpload.ClientID%>').click();
    });

    // the "custom" fileupload box to display the selected image path.
    $('#<%=ProfilePictureUpload.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        $('#<%=ProfilePictureShowFile.ClientID%>').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[HTML]

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="ProfilePictureUpload" CssClass="filename" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="ProfilePictureShowFile" CssClass="fba-txtBox showSelectedFile" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="ProfilePictureBrowsePicture" CssClass="btnYellow" runat="server"  Text="Gennemse" ToolTip="Gennemse billede" />
<asp:Button ID="ProfilePictureUploadButton" CssClass="btnYellow" runat="server" Text="Gem" ToolTip="Gem billede" OnClick="ProfilePictureUploadButton_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="ProfilePictureDeleteButton" CssClass="btnYellow" runat="server" Text="Slet" ToolTip="Slet billede" OnClick="ProfilePictureDeleteButton_Click" EnableViewState="false" />
```

I tried googling if `event.preventDefault()` affects onclick events other than the one it's present in the function for, but with no luck.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();   // Cancels the postback  ...
$('#<%=ProfilePictureUpload.ClientID%>').click();
```

// This is a client side event.

```
OnClick="ProfilePictureUploadButton_Click"  // This is server side event
```

So The client side **.click()** event here is not the same as **Onclick server** event..

Because you are stopping the postback using the **preventDefault** the server side event will obviously not fire...

To fire the server side event you have use either `__doPostback()`  or remove the `preventDefault()` method..

Comment: I switched out the asp.net button with a `<input type="button" />` and removed the `event.preventDefault()` but issues persists. It's very weird.

Comment: The thing is you are clicking ProfilePictureUpload button and expecting ProfilePictureUploadButton_Click  event to be fired...

Comment: They are two different controls? `ProfilePictureUpload` is a fileupload control and `ProfilePictureUploadButton` is a button control. I only expect `ProfilePictureUploadButton_Click` to be triggered whenever I click on `ProfilePictureUploadButton`, not `ProfilePictureUpload`.